# SQL Multiple Join/Sums on Product table

Tags: sql, join

I have the following table containing product sales data from a chain store group. The data is big and ugly, but the only way I can get it from the stores.
For information the table currently holds 22million records, growing by roughly 300k a day and this growth rate will exponentially increase by about 100% on a monthly basis.

```
Store_Purchases(
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[storecode] [int] NULL,
[dtDatum] [datetime] NULL,
[Barcode] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Desc] [varchar](100) NULL,
[qty] [int] NULL,
[amount] [money] NULL,
[TillslipID] [int] NULL)
```

The query I need to pull from this is the top 500 products according to the sum of all sales over a date range. For each of these products I need to show the barcode, description, sum of the quantity sold, sum of the sale amounts, then also the number of till slips that the product was on, and finally the sum total of all products.

So far I have managed to come up with the following. This query takes 2m20s to execute on my server and I think that the "Basket Sum" value is incorrect. I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this in a single query, or even in a stored procedure.

```
SELECT
  a.Barcode, 
  a.Desc, 
  SUM(b.amount) 'Basket SUM',
  COUNT(distinct b.TillslipID) 'Basket Count', 
  Sales.Count, 
  Sales.Amount 
FROM Store_Purchases b WITH (NOLOCK), 
Store_Purchases a WITH (NOLOCK), 
(
  SELECT
    top 500 Barcode,
    sum(qty) "Count", 
    SUM(amount) "Amount" 
  FROM Store_Purchases WITH (NOLOCK)
  WHERE (storecode = 30143)
  AND dtDatum BETWEEN '1-Feb-2013 00:00:00' AND '28-Feb-2013 23:59:59'
  GROUP BY Barcode
  ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC
) AS Sales
WHERE (a.storecode = 30143)
AND a.dtDatum BETWEEN '1-Feb-2013 00:00:00' AND '28-Feb-2013 23:59:59'
AND a.Barcode = Sales.Barcode 
AND a.TillslipID = b.TillslipID 
AND a.storecode = b.storecode
AND b.dtDatum BETWEEN '1-Feb-2013 00:00:00' AND '28-Feb-2013 23:59:59'
GROUP BY a.Barcode, a.Desc, Sales.Count, Sales.Amount
ORDER BYSales.Count DESC
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The distinct on the TillslipID field adds 2 minutes to the execution time of the query, but I couldn't think of any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select top 500 Barcode, [Desc], sum([Count]) as [Count], sum([Amount]) as Amount, sum(BasketSum) as [Basket Sum], count(TillslipID) as [Basket Count]
from (
    select Barcode, [Desc], TillslipID, [Count], [Amount], sum(Amount) over (partition by TillSlipID) as BasketSum
    from (
        select TillslipID, Barcode, [Desc], sum(qty) as [Count], sum(amount) as [Amount]
        FROM ez_Sparbuck_Products p
        WHERE (storecode = 30143) and dtDatum between '1-Feb-2013 00:00:00' and '28-Feb-2013 23:59:59'
        group by Barcode, [Desc], TillslipID, 
    ) t
) t
group by Barcode, [Desc]
```

This makes the assumption that a barcode doesn't have two [Desc]s, which, given the result you're trying to achieve, seems to be the case. If this isn't the case, this same query could be changed to use `partition by Barcode` and `distinct`.

For the volumes of data you are doing this on, I think you will want your clustered index on `dtDatum`, and maybe some kind of partitioning on `storecode`.

Comment: Thanks, this is very very close. I had to add "WHERE (storecode = 30143) and dtDatum between '1-Feb-2013 00:00:00' and '28-Feb-2013 23:59:59'" to the inner join part and now it's pulling the 500 rows in 1 sec. The only problem is that the "Basket Sum" field is not bringing in the correct value. It's close though.

Comment: On second inspection, the basket count is also off. Please take into account that there can be more than one record for the same product with the same TillSlipID.

Comment: OK, see the updated answer for Basket Count, is this better? Can you give a precise definition of Basket SUM? I have read it as the sum of amount for all baskets that contained this Barcode.

Comment: Thanks. You read it correctly, but for instance the query gives 1043 baskets containing product A, but there are actually only 1007 unique baskets with that product. I think this same "duplication" might be the thing messing with the "Basket Sum" field too. Every basket that contains the product should only be added to the basket sum once. I hope this helps.